# Data-binded value won't get updated on UI

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, maui, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a class called `Commander` and it have a property called `CurrentRound` and it gets updated every few seconds internally. I'm using CommunityToolkit.MVVM and In my viewmodel I declared an observable property called `CurrentRound` and in the constructor of my viewmodel I did this `currentRound = _commander.CurrentRound;`.

The strange thing is that when I put a breakpoint in my Commander class and pause the program, I can see the updated value in my xaml file(view) but not on the actual UI.
[image: xaml file updated value]

Commander Class:

```cs
    public partial class Commander
    {
        private readonly Communication communication;
        public Commander(Communication communication) 
        {
            this.communication = communication;
            ThreadStart work = this.NameOfMethodToCall;
            Thread thread = new Thread(work);
            thread.Start();
        }
        private async void NameOfMethodToCall()
        {
            while(true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("hey I'm the second thread!");
                CurrentRound = GetCurrentRound();
            }
        }
        public int CurrentRound { get; private set; } = 1;
   }
```

ViewModel:

```cs
   public partial class ParametersViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        public ParametersViewModel(Commander commander, ...)
        {
            _commander = commander;
            currentRound = _commander.CurrentRound;
            ...
        }
        private readonly Commander _commander;
        ...

        [ObservableProperty]
        int currentRound;
        ...
   }
```

View:

```xml
<Label
   Text="{Binding CurrentRound, StringFormat='Current Round = {0}'}"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"
   FontAttributes="Bold"
   FontSize="Body"/>
...
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Still having the same issue!

ViewModel:

```cs
public partial class ParametersViewModel: ObservableObject
{
   ...
   [ObservableProperty]
   Commander myCommander;
   ...
}
```

View:

```xml
<Label
   Text="{Binding MyCommander.CurrentRound, ...
```

---

**SECOND UPDATE:**

This update solved my issue but I should make my Commander class inherits from ObservableObject and make its CurrentRound property an ObservableProperty, but when using MVVM design pattern I should not worry about UI in the models and business logic, but if I do this, I should care about UI bindings in the models right? **isn't there a better ways of doing this?**

Commander Class:

```cs
    public partial class Commander: ObservableObject
    {
        ...
        [ObservableProperty]
        int currentRound = 1;
        ...
   }
```

Comment: Can you tell me which one are you setting as  BindingConetxt  ParametersViewModel or Commander class?

Comment: Why does your VM have a copy of the property instead of just binding to the property on the Commander class?

Comment: @PrashantRajput my BindingContext is PrametersViewModel

Comment: @Jason is that a copy? I thought it's a reference. you mean something like this `"{Binding MyCommander.CurrentRound}"`?

Comment: Yes, like that.  But your VM will need to have a public property MyCommander.  `int` is a value type, not an object

Comment: @Jason I did it but still having the same issue. (I've added the updated results in my question)

Comment: CurrentRound is not Observable

Comment: @Jason you mean I should make my `Commander` class inherits from `ObservableObject` and make its `CurrentRound` property an `ObservableProperty`? I thought when using MVVM design pattern I should not worry about UI in the models and business logic, but if I do what you are saying, I should care about UI bindings in the models right? isn't there a better ways of doing this?

Comment: the VM/Model should be agnostic about who is consuming it.  Raising an event when a property changes does not violate this - the decision on whether to subscribe to the event and what to do when it fires is up to the subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out something.

Considering:

> and in the constructor of my viewmodel I did this currentRound =
> _commander.CurrentRound

And:

```
[ObservableProperty]
int currentRound;
```

currentRound is a field.
CurrentRound is a property.

Setting fields does not call code. Setting properties does.

All the problems you had, comes from no following naming conventions.
Property A has field _a, not a.